# Shared library not being loaded when php exec() is called

Tags: php, shared-libraries

I am triggering an executable using php

```
$commstr = '/abs/path/to/binary > status.txt &';
echo "Running command: ".$commstr."\n";
shell_exec($commstr);
```

PHP `exec()` or for that matter `system()` or `shell_exec()` works fine because status.txt gets written to, but `cat status.txt` says `error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. This means the binary doesn't get executed

I tried changing my php code to the following without any luck

```
$commstr = 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib ; /abs/path/to/binary > status.txt &';
```

The binary is readable by user `apache` and so are the libraries.

Comment: I guess - since it's not working with absolute path - PHP has nothing to do with that - it's a problem inside external binary

Comment: Well I can run the binary from command line

Comment: So try `cd('/path/to/bin');` in your PHP script then

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I tried that without any luck. I also copied over the .so over to the same dir as the binary

Comment: Are you sure PHP is running as the `apache` user?

Comment: Yes php is running as apache user. But how does that matter so long the binary is executable for both `group` and `others`?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command as sudo.

for example

```
$commstr = 'sudo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib ; /abs/path/to/binary > status.txt &';
```

Comment: No, this results in the same error. Also ideally, user apache should not be a part of sudoers.